# How to stop a thread after the task is finished in python?

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading, kivy-language, kivymd

In the code below, after I click the button for the first time, the spinner (`MDSpinner`) will start to spin and the `logging.info()` will be directed to the `MDLabel`. But after I click the button the second time, there will be two copies of `logging.info()` directed to `MDLabel`. How can I stop the thread after the task `my_thread` is finished? Thanks in advance.

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
import logging
import threading
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.clock import Clock

import time

root_kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    id: main
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "20dp"
    padding: "50dp", "10dp", "50dp", "10dp"

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button4read_mtx
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 4 * dp(48), dp(48)
        text: "Start"
        opposite_colors: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_release: app.analyze_data()
    MDSpinner:
        id: spinder4button
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(46), dp(46)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        active: False
    MDLabel:
        id: test_label_log
        text: "Log"
        halign: "left"
'''

exit_flag = 0
def my_thread(log, app):
    app.root.ids.spinder4button.active = True
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        log.info("Step %s", i)
    app.root.ids.spinder4button.active = False

class MDLabelHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, label, level=logging.NOTSET):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level=level)
        self.label = label

    def emit(self, record):
        "using the Clock module for thread safety with kivy's main loop"
        def f(dt=None):
            self.label.text += "\n" + self.format(record)  #"use += to append..."
        Clock.schedule_once(f)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(root_kv)
        return root
    def analyze_data(self):
        log = logging.getLogger("my.logger")
        log.level = logging.DEBUG
        log.addHandler(MDLabelHandler(self.root.ids.test_label_log, logging.DEBUG))
        #thread_info = _thread.start_new(my_thread, (log, self, ))
        #print(thread_info)
        x = threading.Thread(target=my_thread, args=(log, self, ))
        x.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: You can terminate a thread by installing trace into it. This will cause the thread to exit. For an example of one possible implementation, here we go: https://web.archive.org/web/20130503082442/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-May/281943.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread is terminating, as it should, when the task completes. That is not the problem. The problem is that you are adding a new logging handler each time you run `analyze_data()`. The fix is to only add one handler:

```
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.log = None

    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(root_kv)
        return root

    def analyze_data(self):
        if self.log is None:
            self.log = logging.getLogger("my.logger")
            self.log.level = logging.DEBUG
            self.log.addHandler(MDLabelHandler(self.root.ids.test_label_log, logging.DEBUG))
        #thread_info = _thread.start_new(my_thread, (log, self, ))
        #print(thread_info)
        x = threading.Thread(target=my_thread, args=(self.log, self, ))
        x.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. You code works perfect. I just don't understand why my code doesn't work. My understanding is that a  new `log` in my code will be created every time I invoke `analyze_data()`. Could you please give me more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it is not a new logger, but a new `Handler` that gets created each time in your code. The logger loops through all the `Handlers` that it has when `log.info()` is called.